# hide part of the URL

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I use `swagger2`. I configured it to redirect to `swagger-ui.html` when the use access the root path.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer index() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/swagger-ui.html");
        }
    };
}
```

As I configured in application.yml the `context-path` as `/api`, now the when user tries to access `/api` he is redirected to `/api/swagger-ui.html`.

But I don't want to display `swagger-ui.html` at all and leave only `/api`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below java script on the landing html page

```
<script>
    history.replaceState('data to be passed', 'Title of the page', "/api/");
</script>
```